# Double sum of a series in Matlab

Tags: matlab, sum, double, series

I would like to run this function in Matlab:

[image: function of duble sums]

where z is a [N1xN2] matrix, x is a [M1xM2] matrix and y is a [P1xP2] matrix.

N1=M1+P1-1 and N2=M2+P2-1

I am now trying to do it using 4 for-loops which might be quite time consuming for large matrices.

I found `symsum()` function in Matlab but I cannot see how to adjust it to work for double sums. Is there an easier way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

The formula which you are trying to calculate is 2D discrete convolution.

In Matlab, there is a function which calculates it automatically, it is called conv2.

Use the following code:

```
Z = conv2(x,y);
```

Comment: I know this, but I need to do it this way and then compare it to conv2.